# regex_replace in ansible isn't replacing string with capture group 1

Tags: regex, ansible

so my main.yml file is using vars + a regex_replace filter and what I'm seeing is that I either get no response or the matched string is taken out and i'm left with the rest...

```
hosts: jenkinsservers
vars:
  teamname: "{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('(?<=\\-)(.*?)(?=\\.)', '\\1') }}"
```

example hosts:

```
jenkins-team1.example.com
```

result: teamname continues to be `jenkins-team1.example.com`

however, if I remove , '\1' , leaving just

```
"{{ inventory_hostname | regex_replace('(?<=\\-)(.*?)(?=\\.)') }}"
```

then teamname var results in `jenkins-.example.com`

so I believe the regex is matching the "team1" as intended, why is it that \1 doesn't make the whole var just the captured string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the output equivalent to the captured string using `replace` and a backreference, then you should *match* everything before the `-` *and* match everything after the `.`, rather than use lookbehind and lookahead (the whole match will be replaced by the second argument):

```
regex_replace('.+-(.*?)\\..+', '\\1')
```

When you use lookbehind and lookahead as you did, only the characters that were actually matched (that is, the ones in your capture group) get replaced. Lookaround doesn't match characters by themselves, they just identify a *position* in a string.

Compare

https://regex101.com/r/lGUp0X/1

(matches `team` and replaces `team` with `team`, the first captured group - in other words, no change)

with

https://regex101.com/r/lGUp0X/2

(matches the whole string and replaces it with `team`, the first captured group)

Comment: Perfect, I see what you mean, thanks for the explanation... working as expected